# Proof linked to linear algebraic equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Let a, b, c, e, f and g be real numbers such that:

e/a + b/f = 1

f/b + c/g = 1

Prove that abc + efg = 0

I have tried all possible manipulations at my end but am unable to prove the identity. Help or hint appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

if $e=0$ then $b=f$ and $c=0$

otherwise let
$$  \lambda = \frac{b}{f} \; , \; \;  \sigma = \frac{a}{e} \; , \; \; \tau = \frac{c}{g} \; . $$

Then
$$   \sigma = \frac{1}{1-\lambda}  = \frac{-1}{\lambda-1} $$
$$   \tau = \frac{\lambda-1}{\lambda} $$

And
$$  \sigma \tau = \frac{-1}{\lambda} $$
so that
$$ \color{red}{ \sigma \tau \lambda = -1,}$$
which is the desired result

Comment: Many thanks for such a simple solution